# Como mudar nome de imagem com python?

Tags: python

Quero mudar/alterar, o nome de um conjunto de imagens.

Eu tenho o código em python que faz isso, o problema é que ele gera da seguinte forma "123image.jpg" e que queria "image123.jpg". Como ajustar isso no código?

```
import os 

path = '/Users/gustavo/projects/dump/tf_files/locate_vaccancies/vaccancy'
files = os.listdir(path)


for index, file in enumerate(files):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, 'vaccancy'.join([str(index), '.jpg'])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer isso você pode utilizar o código abaixo:

```
import os
from shutil import move
```

Definindo o caminho e a extensão dos arquivos

```
caminho = 'C:/caminho/para_as_imagens'
ext = '.jpg'
```

Pegando a lista de nomes dos arquivos na pasta indicada

```
arquivos = os.listdir(caminho)
```

Verificando se os arquivos terminam com a extensão desejada

```
arquivos = [arquivo for arquivo in arquivos if arquivo.endswith(ext)]
```

Aqui é onde acontece o mudança do nome do arquivo

```
[move(arquivo, f'imagem{i}.jpg') for i, arquivo in enumerate(arquivos)]
```

---

Código

```
import os
from shutil import move

caminho = 'C:/caminho/para_as_imagens'
ext = '.jpg'

arquivos = os.listdir(caminho)
arquivos = [arquivo for arquivo in arquivos if arquivo.endswith(ext)]

[move(arquivo, f'imagem{i}.jpg') for i, arquivo in enumerate(arquivos)]
```

Comment: Valeu, vou tentar.

Comment: Fala lmonferrari.
Rodei meu arquivo python e ele me apontou erro de syntaxe aqui:

    [move(arquivo, f'g{i}.jpg') for i, arquivo in enumerate(arquivos)]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Nas aspas simples depois do jpg

Comment: Você utiliza qual versão do python? Talvez este resolva o problema no seu caso: `[move(arquivo, 'imagem'+str(i)+'.jpg') for i, arquivo in enumerate(arquivos)]`

Answer (score 0):

dessa forma você consegue adicionar o numero após o nome da imagem:

```
import os 

path = '/Users/gustavo/projects/dump/tf_files/locate_vaccancies/vaccancy'
files = os.listdir(path)

for index, file in enumerate(files):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, f'image{index}.png'))



Dessa outra forma é possível adicionar diversos numeros:


import os 

path = '/Users/gustavo/projects/dump/tf_files/locate_vaccancies/vaccancy'
files = os.listdir(path)

for index, file in enumerate(files):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, f'image{index+1, index+2, index+3}.png'))
```